# REGEX - All attributes without quotes

Tags: javascript, regex, attributes

I have following html string

```
<span onclick="Popup=window.open('C_SPD').URL;','Popup','menubar=No,toolbar=No,scrollbars=Yes,width=600,height=500,top=20,left=60,resizable=yes');return  fallse;" href="#">xyz</span>

<a href=mailto@abc.com?subject=LongTerm  third=third>esc@abc.com</a>
```

I need to put double quotes around attributes wherever missing.

Comment: This is a parsing job. Use a server side language or NodeJS. In any case in html5 no quotes is valid. BTW, you have a typo `return  fallse;`

Comment: I need to fix it in javascript

Comment: HTML Tidy is your best friend. ref to http://tidy.sourceforge.net/.